# Windows 8 app: Bing maps javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, bing-maps

I'm working on a Windows 8 app that will include Bing Maps, but i have a problem when i try it out in Visual Studio an error comes up that says

> Unhandled expection at line 19, column 17 in
>   ms-appx://fe56a029-c8e7-41e5-a755-b22871affb67/doglatrinemapsearch.html

`0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Microsoft' is undefined`

My code looks like this:

```
 var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"),
                       {
                           credentials: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                           center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(55.559549, 12.927881),
                           mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.birdseye,
                           zoom: 100
                       });
```

Comment: most likely explanation is you don't have the references for the maps library included.

Comment: But i have
js/bing.js

and the References

Comment: Did you wait till document is loaded ? where did you put the code? in `onload` function ?

Comment: yeah i use <body onload="GetMap();">

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to load the map before the map control is finished loading. Take a look a the following code sample and blog post on creating cross platform Bing Maps apps using the JavaScript control:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cross-Platform-Bing-Maps-e96600d5
http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/06/28/cross-platform-development-with-bing-maps-and-phonegap.aspx